# node moment - endOf('day') for a specific timezone

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I want to create a moment object for 23:59:59 today, For a specific timezone, e.g. Asia/Jerusalem

running `moment().endOf('day').utc('Asia/Jerusalem')`

returns `moment.utc("2019-04-17T23:59:59.999+00:00")`

Which is not good, because 23:59 UTC+0 != 23:59 UTC+2 (Jerusalem timezone)

setting the default timezone, i.e. `process.env.TZ = 'Asia/Jerusalem'`, solves it, but I don't want to change the process env each time I need this.

**How can I create a moment object that has a fixed timezone?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`moment-timezone`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) for this.

```js
const moment = require('moment-timezone');

const dt = moment().tz('Asia/Jerusalem').endOf('day');

dt.toISOString(); // 2019-04-17T20:59:59.999Z
dt.format(); // 2019-04-17T23:59:59+03:00
```

Yes, `Asia/Jerusalem` is `+03:00` now.

Answer (score -1):

I think you may be able to use this to get the end of day in any timezone without the use of any large lib or outdated timezone offset thingy that moment.js sometimes have to update

```js
var date = new Date()
var options = {
  // hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric',
  year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric',
  // hour12: false,
  timeZoneName: 'short',
  timeZone: 'Asia/Jerusalem'
};
var date = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('xx-XX', options)
  .format(date).split(' ') // [date, offset]

date = `${date[0]} 23:59:59:999 ${date[1]}` // use end of day
  

// end of day in Asia/Jerusalem
console.log(date)
date = new Date(date)

// end of day in Asia/Jerusalem with no timezone
console.log(date)


// end of day in Asia/Jerusalem with our local timezone
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString(), date.toLocaleTimeString())
```